# Using locally downloaded wheel as dependency for package

Tags: python, gdal, python-wheel, python-packaging

I've developed a package which depends on `gdal`. The problem is, that installing `gdal` on Windows can be tricky, so in order to mitigate the problems and ensure portability, I would like to use Christoph Gohlke's [unofficial binary](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) as `gdal` dependency for my package.

The binary comes as a `wheel` which can't be easily downloaded programmatically.

**So my question is:**

Is there any way to download the `wheel` locally, and include it as a dependency in my built distribution `wheel` when I package my code?

Or is there any convention or other problem that would prohibit such an approach?

I've tried googling extensively, but I haven't found anything concise which would answer my question.